visionOS 1.1 Not Supported
I am trying to create sample visionOS app and wanted to do try little hands on, but it shows "visionOS 1.1 Not Supported". Find the below screenshot for specs of Mac, can somebody through me an insight on this and what should be best specs require for future development.



Developing for visionOS requires a Mac with Apple silicon.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos#Overview
There was a window of time where this worked on Intel... there's some threads on the forum.
As for Apple Silicon, I've run the toolset briefly on a base MacBook Air M1 (8 / 256).
I strongly recommend using 16 GB RAM (it seemed to run fine, but I doubt you would want to be running Xcode-only).
Everything can fit in a base storage, but tightly.
I wasn't able to find any clear cut hardware requirements from Apple.
